# How can I update a custom sticker on a card on Trello using the Trello API?

Tags: put, trello, sticker, trelloapi

After posting a custom sticker on a card, I followed the documentation and it says that the endpoint to update it should be:

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{id}/stickers/{idSticker}?top={top}&left={left}&zIndex={zIndex}&key=APIKey&token=APIToken'
```

In order to get the {{idSticker}} I need, I sent beforehand a GET request on Tests section:

```
// get idSticker from response
const idSticker = jsonResponse[0].id;
```

I get and ID, which corresponds with the custom sticker I want to update. I checked that hardcoding the ID that I got and sending a new POST request. It's the same sticker.

```
{{base_url}}/1/cards/{{card_id}}/stickers/{{custom_sticker_id}}?top=10&left=0&zIndex=0&key={{key}}&token={{token}}
```

and I get the response "Invalid idSticker".

What Am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If it is an Update, should it not be a PUT request instead? (not POST)... Beyond that, a sticker on a card has a unique sticker id and the general id of the custom sticker (the "image" id)... Sounds like you might have these two confused